# Style children elements based on the count within their parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is a made-up example to represent a type of problem I have on a daily basis, when I'm using a content management system that sets up the HTML for tons of webpages and I need general ways of applying CSS according to mockups. I'm wondering if there is a non-Javascript way of solving it.

Suppose I have a `div` of class `some-div`, which will either have 1 or 2 child `div`s. When it has 1 child `div`, that child should have a `red` background; when it has 2 child divs, they should have `blue` backgrounds:

```html
    <div class="some-class">
        <div>
             <p>The background of this should be red.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="some-class">
        <div>
             <p>The background of this should be blue.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
             <p>The background of this should be blue</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a way of doing this in CSS? A hack, perhaps?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has

Comment: Probably hypocritical on my own part but I'm willing to let this question slide because it's clearly well-written and well-constructed, and the solution is non-obvious. I would totally understand if the OP had no idea what to try to begin with.

Answer (score 11):

Well, I'll cave.  Here's my solution

http://jsfiddle.net/z7ajmh5z/

```css
.some-class div {
    background: blue;
}

.some-class div:first-child:last-child {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="some-class">
        <div>
             <p>The background of this should be red.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="some-class">
        <div>
             <p>The background of this should be blue.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
             <p>The background of this should be blue</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### Edit

Apparently, there is also the `:only-child` selector which I found by looking into [@LiorRaz's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641597/is-it-possible-to-do-this-with-only-css/27641692?noredirect=1#comment43702084_27641597)

It has [about as much support as `:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child)

Would be worth at least looking into.  Here's an embedded example.

```css
.some-class div {
  background: blue
}

.some-class div:only-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="some-class">
        <div>
             <p>The background of this should be red.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="some-class">
        <div>
             <p>The background of this should be blue.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
             <p>The background of this should be blue</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Perfect and with wider support

Comment: Browser support for the level 3 structural pseudo-classes is identical. No browser I'm aware of supports more or fewer pseudo-classes than others. Don't worry about browser support unless you need to develop for IE8.

Comment: Oh, that's right - Chrome has [all kinds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335187/complex-selector-dont-work-in-last-blink-version-nth-child2nth-last-child2) of [issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436485/google-chrome-and-nth-last-child) with `:nth-last-child()`. IE9+ is fine.

Answer (score 8):

you can target the div with css pseudo [**FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zz78znd6/)

CSS

```
.some-class div:only-child
{
    background: red;
}
.some-class div:not(:only-of-type)
{
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: You don't need pseudo-classes for both cases.

Comment: That is some really slick CSS.  Compatibility is again hovering around the IE 9 mark just like all the `:first-child`, `:nth-of-type`, and `:last-child` solutions.

Answer (score 5):

For modern browsers that support the `:nth-last-of-type` (*http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-last-child-pseudo*)

```
.some-class div{
    background-color: red;
}

.some-class div + div,
.some-class div:nth-last-child(2){
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ofhb3hj1/

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do this with `nth-of-type`. Set all of them to `background-color: red` then you can target every `.some-class` starting after the 1st one and overwrite the `div` color to be blue:

```
.some-class div{
  background-color: red;
}

.some-class:nth-of-type(1n+2) div{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q7gk608y/2/)

**UPDATE FOR ckuijjer**

Who said:  `don't think this is a solution. The question is can you color the child <div>'s a red if there it's the only child and blue if there are two children.`

Yes you can. Here is how:

```
.some-class:nth-of-type(1n+2) div:first-child{
  background-color: red;
}

.some-class:nth-of-type(1n+2) div:nth-of-type(1n+2){
 background-color: blue;
}
```

[FIDDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q7gk608y/6/)

Bottom line is this is how to do it, no matter what the OP was trying to portray in his/her explanation and whether or not I or anyone else understood what he/she actually wanted, the answer (question title was: `Is it possible to do this with only CSS?`) is: yes, it can be done with just CSS. Just need the right equation.

Comment: I don't think this is a solution. The question is can you color the child `<div>`'s a red if there it's the only child and blue if there are two children.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli there could be definite complications if the HTML were to change and the `nth-of-type` may have to be adjusted, but the OP asked for a specific example.

Comment: yes, but not this one. His question is about the two child divs, not the containers.. (*its two examples he gives not a big one*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli look at the fiddle HTML text and tell me thats not exactly what he was asking for...

Comment: @jmore009 nice! i really love seeing all the different pseudo class solutions.

Comment: Your 2nd approach is still not what the TO expects. He/she expects kind of a hypotetical `.some-class:child-count(2) div {background: blue; } .some-class:child-count(1) div { background: red; }`. And it should (probably) work if both `div.some-class` are alone in the DOM. I admit, the TO should clarify this point.

Comment: also his first sentence: `This is a made-up example to represent a type of problem I have on a daily basis` this was a hypothetical question

Comment: 1st: @ckuijjer you've changed the words in the paragraphs to match the output. Just use the TO's markup and you'll see your outcome is wrong. Try removing one of the `div`s or add more in an alternating order to test it. 2nd: If you're not sure what the TO expects *ask for clarification*. For me the TO's explation was clear, so was it for 3 other. @jmore009: Even for "made-up examples" a clear question should get a _correct_ answer.

Comment: @try-catch-finally good catch! I was just so happy with all the pseudo class solutions that I didn't take a good look at this solution

Comment: As others have already mentioned, I wouldn't rely on the assumption that the first `.some-class` will only ever contain one child and the second element (or subsequent elements) will only ever contain two children. Otherwise it makes the question deceptively easy. If you wanted to stretch the "possible with only CSS" definition you could patch together some really brittle hack and call it "possible", only for it to fall apart the moment any of the markup is changed (which, in fact, is what would happen with this answer). How would that be useful?

Answer (score -1):

Just add a class to all the ones you want red, and a separate one to all that you want blue.
Example:

```
<div class="some-class">
    <div class="red">
         <p>The background of this should be red.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="some-class">
    <div class="blue">
         <p>The background of this should be blue.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
         <p>The background of this should be blue</p>
    </div>
</div>

.blue {
background: blue;
}

.red {
background: red;
}
```